# Can an Angular Component also be used as an Authentication Guard

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I'd like to move the CanActivate method out of my `Auth.guard.ts` to rather be in each pages component. The reason for this is that my auth guard file is getting cluttered and I think logically it makes sense for the permissions handling of a component to be placed in that components typescript file.

I tried the following but wasn't successful.

Here I added the `implements CanActivate` and added the `canActivate(route,state)` method to my component `MyPageComponent`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-page',
    templateUrl: './my-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-page.component.scss']
})
export class MyPageComponent implements OnInit, CanActivate {
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return true; // or return false
    }
    // all other code for the component below here
    constructor()...
    ngOnInit()...
```

then in the app-routing.module.ts file I added

```
{
    path: "My-Page",
    component: MyPageComponent,
    canActivate: [MyPageComponent]
},
```

I end up getting `NullInjectorErrors`.

So my question is, is this possible to move my canActivate method into my component? any other way to occomplish this?

Thanks for any help that's provided.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is basically "no". A route guard is an `@Injectable`, not a `@Component`. If you have different authorization patterns for your different routes, I suggest you write multiple guards.

Angular has a set way of doing things. You can do things differently, but you'll be breaking Angular patterns, and that's generally a bad idea. Guards are for route protection, components are for showing stuff to the user.

Comment: Thanks @Will I thought this might be the case. Thanks for the clarification on why it's not working.